# How to delete a page using wordpress rest api through curl

Tags: wordpress, curl, wordpress-rest-api

I have done all pages listed in core PHP application using wordpress REST API with CURL but I can't delete that pages with CURL.I got message "{code: "rest_cannot_delete", message: "Sorry, you are not allowed to delete this post.}" every time.

Here is my code.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/37';
$postdata = 37; //pageID

function callrestapi_curlDelete($url, $postdata) {

    $postdata_json = json_encode($postdata);
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata_json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

    echo json_decode($resp, TRUE);

}
```

Or if I tried via this code than I am getting the same error.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/15 ',
      method: 'DELETE',
      crossDomain: true,
      beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('admin:admin@123'));
      },
      success: function( data, txtStatus, xhr ) {
               console.log( data );
               console.log( xhr.status );
                            }
 });
```

Comment: use admin login credentials.

Comment: I have no idea how to pass through it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to post any data to delete a page/post. The URL is enough as you have already included the ID you want to delete. See example below:

```
$postid = 108;

$rest_api_url = "http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/post/".$postid;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rest_api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Notice the variable $token for Authorization which i'm assuming you already know how to generate through basic auth.

This will put the post into trash, if you want to delete permanently then add the following to the end of your URL.

```
?force=true
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your cURL code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username" . ":" . "password");
```

don't forget to install and activated basic auth master plugin